# How do I make my bot get the channel Id from where the user ran the command from? (Discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py, customization

So, I have made a bot that fetches **memes** from **reddit** and posts those memes to a **Discord** Channel.

The only reason the word 'Discord Channel' is not *plural*, is because at the moment I can only **input** the channel I want to send those memes to *manually*, by *inserting* the ID into my code..

**A very big problem when it comes to releasing my bot to the public.**
This is all I have so far.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

@client.command()
async def config(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Hello, please go to the channel, you would like me to post memes to, and do am.memechannel')
    
    
@client.command()
async def memechannel(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Memes will now be sent in this channel')
```

Please tell me if I need to import a few things to make this happen!
Also, I know this question can be answered by reading the Discord Py API but I don't know how to read the API.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the channel object with [`ctx.channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.channel). Then you can get the id with `ctx.channel.id`. So you can do:

```
@client.command()
async def memechannel(ctx):
    channel_id = ctx.channel.id
    await ctx.send('Memes will now be sent in this channel')
```

Comment: Do I need to make a data base?